# choosing between are or were past or present

Tags: past-tense

The researchers also collected data from 25 park users in Berlin using a questionnaire. All participants **are** members of the environmental council, thus, **are** likely to be committed to .......

should i use participants are or participants were, and are likely or were likely?

Comment: Both should do based on the context.  If you write, suppose, the process/steps followed in your research/ study, it can well be written in present tense.  If you portray it as things happened in the past, 'were' should be used.

Comment: //should i use participants are or participants were, and are likely or were likely?// You should also know that a) a sentence should start in upper case, b) ' I ' shouldn't be written as i, c) minimum punctuation should be done in a question so that readers can understand your question.